# Creating a Word Combinator Tool in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is an exercise from a class on CodeLesson.com: Write a program that will accept a list of words from a user. These can either be one per line or all on a single line and delimited in some way (with commas perhaps). Then print out every combination of two words. For example, if a user were to type in `book,bus,car,plane`, then the output would be something like:

> bookbook bookbus bookcar bookplane busbook busbus buscar busplane
>   carbook carbus carcar carplane planebook planebus planecar planeplane"

Answer (score 1):

If you want a kickstart then use the built in [Array#repeated_permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation). For doing it yourself, think of a way to loop the array; inside that loop, loop again.

Answer (score 0):

You need an algorithm to obtain "permutations with repetition". Google it and you'll find many pages with explanations and algorithms. Since it's a learning assignment I won't provide an actual implementation :) but see here for instance:

[Permutation with repetition without allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950769/permutation-with-repetition-without-allocate-memory)

Now, you say none of your ideas are working. Perhaps if you add some of them to your question you can get specific tips on why they're not working and how to get your algorithm to work.

Answer (score 0):

As a first idea, you could loop over each element in the array of words, and then loop over each word again inside the loop:

```
# Ask the user for a comma-separated input.
input = gets

# Split the input into an array, and map
# each element of the array to the same 
# element, but with surrounding whitespace
# removed.
words = input.split(',').map { |w| w.strip }

# Iterate over each word.
words.each do |w1|
  # For each word, iterate over 
  # all words once again.
  words.each do |w2|
    # Skip the loop if the two
    # words are the same.
    next if w1 == w2
    puts w1 + w2 
  end
end
```

However, there is a more concise way of saying "loop through the array, and loop through the array again inside each loop": it's called repeated permutation. The method [Array#repeated_permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) allows you to do this. It takes as a parameter the length of the permutation (in our case, the length is two: we iterate once over the array, and then once again inside each loop). Here's how that would look:

```
input = gets
words = input.split(',').map { |w| w.strip }
words.repeated_permutation(2) do |w1, w2|
  next if w1 == w2
  puts w1 + w2
end
```

Hope this helps.